# Symfony entity one to many for existing tables

Tags: php, symfony

I have been checking the documentation and got confused, can someone advise me how to add one-to-many relationships for existing tables? Adequately userid is supposed to refer to the user id.

Entity for a user that may have multiple doors

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['username'], message: '321')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Entity for the doors

```
#[ORM\Table(name: '`doors`')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['serialNumber'], message: '312132')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DoorsRepository::class)]
class Doors
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $userid = null;

    private ?string $purchaseFilename = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): static
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the *make* tool, for example `bin/console make:entity User` it will detect that it exists and you can add a new property, when it asks for the *Field type* use `relation` then follow the prompts to create a *OneToMany* and set the *Doors* entity as the relation [[REF](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#the-manytoone-onetomany-association)]. This will create a migration file within your migrations folder, running `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` will run the actual migration.

Comment: I know this command, what I mean is that the columns by which I want to merge already exist - it is to them that I want to add relationships i.e. ID (users) and userID (doors)

Answer (score 0):

as your properties already exist, you have to update their annotations like based on [Symfony Associations Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship) and the type used.

```php
    class Doors {
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'doors')]
    private User $user;
    
    public function getUser(): ?User 
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    
    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
class User {
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Door::class, mappedBy: 'user')]
    private Collection $doors;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->doors = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    
    public function getDoors():Collection
    {
        return $this->doors;
    }
}
```

Then you will have to run make a new migration and run it using:

```
php bin/console make:migration 
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

In addition, you may take a look at [How to embed a collection of form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) to handle your forms.

If it's was helpull, make sure to accept the answer !

**Edit:** as you mentionned, the column already exists in your database so after updating your code as I showed you right before, you may specify the colomn name for your property as follow (see [Doctrine Annotations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column)):

```php
class Doors {
     #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'doors')]
     #[Column(name: 'user_id')]
     private User $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an easy way to add relations in Symfony.

You can use the command `php bin/console make:entity`.

Then call your entity (in your example `Doors`), add a field `user`, declare type `OneToMany` (or see more relation types with the `relation` key), related the entity to `User`, and voila.

Then `php bin/console make:migration` : it will write the change in `migrations` folder ; you'll see it automatically add a field `user_id` in Door table, related to your `user.id` (as id is the identifier of your User entity).
And `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` : queries will be executed in your db.

I hope it will help